# How to return value without decimal

Tags: jquery, decimal

I am trying to find the BMI value, in this BMI calculator, however the result is coming in decimal value but I want it to return a whole number only.

For example: after calculating BMI value it returns 82.25235, but I want it to return 82. How can I do that?

```js
function calculateBMI() {
 
    var weight = $("#txtWeight").val();
 
    var height = $("#txtHeight").val();
 
    BMIScore = weight/(height/100*height/100);

}
```

```html
<label id="label">Height:</label>
<input type="number" name="text" placeholder="Height(Cms)" id="txtHeight" />

<label id="label"> Weight:</label>
<input type="number" name="text"  placeholder="Weight(Kgs)" id="txtWeight" />

<a href="#" data-role="button" id="button" onClick="calculateBMI()">Show</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Discarding decimals

In (*original*) title you asked to `take value with out (sic) decimal`. In such case just let your `BMIScore` throguh `parseInt()`.

> The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

Read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp).

### Rounding to nearest integer

You may want to round to the nearest integer, instead. That way you minimize error due to presenting value as an integer. In such case just let your `BMIScore` throguh `round()`.

> The round() method rounds a number to the nearest integer.

Read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) or [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp).

### Example based on your code

```js
function calculateBMI() {

  var weight = $("#txtWeight").val();

  var height = $("#txtHeight").val();

  BMIScore = parseInt(weight / (height / 100 * height / 100));
  alert(BMIScore);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="label">Height:</label>
<input type="number" name="text" placeholder="Height(Cms)" id="txtHeight">

<label id="label">Weight:</label>
<input type="number" name="text" placeholder="Weight(Kgs)" id="txtWeight">

<a href="#" data-role="button" id="button" onClick="calculateBMI()">Show</a>
```

### Few notes

- You don't need jQuery for this task. `$("#id").val()` can be replaced with `document.getElementById('id').value`.
- Your `<label>`s have the same `id`s. Only one element in entire document should have particular `id`.
- Don't use inline `onclick` attribute on your button, use `document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', calculateBMI);`.

Comment: suggest you use the [link to MDN on parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) instead of w3schools, [here is why](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @webeno: I personally find MDN more accurate and "rich" source too (though W3Schools got much better than it was some time ago, by the way). Links to MDN were added.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to round --

Assuming that your BMIScore is a number:

Always round down:
`Math.floor(BMIScore);`

Always round up:
`Math.ceil(BMIScore);`

Normal rounding:
`Math.round(BMIScore);`

Typecast to Integer:
`parseInt(BMIScore);`